# Issue when trying to retrieve data from Firebase with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Firebase database. I use JSON to get the data. Using SwiftyJSON library.

**Here is my code:**

```
func retrieveUserDatabaseAdress(userID: String) {

    let userRef = ref.child("users").child(userID)

    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let json = JSON(snapshot)
        print("test")
        self.address = json["address"].stringValue
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

    }) { error in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

**Here is my Database hierarchy**

```
-users  
---S4KaKn5Qz4bDDha57DMLcnaCHn22
-------address: ...
-------email: ...
-------name: ...
-------tel: ...
```

**Issue:** it always retrieves a nil value. Plus, the **print("test")** is not executed.

I checked if the user was logged in to get the read rules: it's ok.
I also tried with other methods, not working.
My Firebase database seems to be correctly configured because I can write data... But can't read data...

Comment: Yeah I already used it and it's work fine. I also tried without JSON and it didn't work.

Comment: Pass parameter inside JSON function as snapshot.children

Comment: Write an anwser with the code you suggest please! ;)

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV delete everything in your block except the snapshot in line and write this: let dictionary = snapshot.value as! [Sting: Any] then print the dictionary and tell me if it show some data.

Comment: It still doesn't work... Returning nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pass root path of Database as "users". 
This code works fine in my database. It might works for your case. You should try:)

```
let childRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users")

        childRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            for item in snapshot.children {

                 let json = JSON(item)
                print(json)

            }

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let json = JSON(value)
        print(json)
    } else {
        // No value
    }
}, withCancel: { (error) in
    print(error)
})
```

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: Are you calling your function correctly? Try to print something outside `observeSingleEvent`

Comment: It works when I print something outside: I printed "start" and "stop' at the begining and at the end of the `observeSingleEvent`... This is working. But all prints inside the `observeSingleEvent` are not executed and this return nil... So weird!

Comment: Okay, so are you sure that there is something in `id` you are passing as a parameter? Try to change this line `let userRef = ref.child("users").child(userID)` to this `let userRef = ref.child("users")` and print `snapshot`.

Comment: The prints are not executed in the `observeSingleEvent` ! I can't print a String value like "OK" but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: If you want, you can share your code with me and I can take a look

Comment: No, can be just this file.

Comment: I found something!! The request is taking like 10s to receive the data! (I don't know why, i got 1Gb download and good ping). Then it makes crash my app because of nil value in the next step of my app. Because the function doesn't wait to receive the data and continue to exectue the code! I discover this by trying to create a recursive func that launch the request until the variable is no more a ni; And after a while, the snapshot is printed... Now, how can I make the request as long as it takes to retrieve data?? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wow 1GB haha, that's a lot. Well, no problem :)